# Can I use JWTAuthentication twice for a login authentication?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

In my login First place I wanted to send OTP and second place I wanted to verify the OTP and then return the token.

I am using `rest_framework_simplejwt` JWTAuthentication. First place I am verifying the user and sending the OTP, not returning the token and second place I am verifying the OTP and returning the token.

Let me know If this is the correct way to use? If not how can I implement this using JWTAuthentication.

OR If this is not correct way to use, can I implement like first place use **Basic authentication** to verify the user and second place **jwt authentication** to verify the OTP and send the tokens. Let me know your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**What I understood?**

You need to send an OTP to the current user who is hitting your send_otp route after checking if the user exists or not in your system and then verify_otp route which will verify the OTP that the user has sent in the API alongwith it's corresponding mobile_number/email_id.

**How to do it?**

- *send_otp* - Keep this route open, you don't need an authentication for this, not even Basic Auth (that's how it works in industry), just get the mobile_number from the user in the request, check whether it exists in the DB, and send the OTP to this number, and set the OTP to the corresponding user in your cache maybe for rechecking (redis/memcache). Use throttling for this route so that nobody will be able to exploit this API of yours.
- *verify_otp* - This route will also be open (no authentication_class/permission_classes), get the mobile_number/email id + OTP from the user, verify it in cache, if verified, generate the token using **TokenObtainPairSerializer** and send the refresh + access token in the response, if the OTP is incorrect, send 401.

Comment: Thanks @sajal-sharma, this is really useful.

Comment: Happy to help :)